# EPPlus import file xlsm

Tags: c#, epplus, excel-import

I am trying to import an xlsm file using EPPlus. I found the link that said EPPlus doesn't support this : [Convert XLSM to XLSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175343/convert-xlsm-to-xlsx) . It's very old so I wanted to know if it supports it now ? If not, is there any way to do this with EPPlus by converting to XLSX but the way should be independent on Microsoft updates and just dependent on libraries used at the time of building the program. 
My current code looks like this :

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Program.source_path, s));
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
   {
       ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];
       for (int row = 9; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
       {
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will copy all content from the source xlsm file to a target xlsx file.

```
      using (var target = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\target.xlsx")))
        {
            using (var source = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\source.xlsm")))
            {

                foreach (var worksheet in source.Workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    target.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet.Name, worksheet);
                }
            }
            target.Save();
        }
```

Comment: You should put the target ExcelPackage in a using statement too. This is the best EPPlus solution so far, but I tried and I lose the Table formating in a range (when I opened the Excel, it says it found a problem and tries to recover, then the table is gone.)

Comment: I am getting the exception : Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: encoder .. everytime

Comment: Strange, I have tested it, what line is giving you this exception?

Comment: It's really strange. The error just changed when trying to debug: "Root element is missing." My code looks like same. This error is at 'foreach' statement.

Comment: seems like source file is corrupted, what version of EPPLUS are u using?

Comment: Probably, the file is corrupted. The latest version for EPPlus on nuget..It's v4.1.1.. I just tried the ExcelDataReader nuget. That one worked. We can still try to figure out this issue..!!!

Comment: so it is failing to get source.Workbook.Worksheets?

Comment: Yes. It is failing on that step.

Comment: is it still "root element is missing" ? this is an xml error, maybe your file's xml needs to be fixed before you can read it