# File wont open after saving

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have some code that is suppose to enter some values into several excel workbooks. Right now the program doesn't even put any values into the workbooks and only saves them. Even like this i get this error when opening the files: Excel cannot open the file **.xlsm because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I have writen many programs that work with excel files and never had this problem. In the code you can see that i basically just go through a for loop and save the file.

```
try
{
   fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath) + '\\' + partners[partner].partnerName + @"\PDP_ExSumm_" + partners[partner].partnerName + ".xlsm");
   using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
   {
         ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
         for (int cell = 0; cell < ExSummCells.Count; cell++)
         {
             if (ExSummCells[cell] != "")
             {
             // worksheet.Cells[ExSummCells[cell]].Value = partners[partner].exSummData[partner];
             }
   excelPackage.Save();
   }
}
```

Comment: Two questions - are you sure the .xlsm shouldn't be .xlsx? And, where does ExcelPackage come from?

Comment: Are you sure it's valid XLSM file to start with?  Try making a copy of the file, rename the extension to .zip. Is it a valid zip file? Can you unzip it and go into it? What happens if you create a brand new XLSM file with Excel, and save it, and then try to open it with EPPlus?

Comment: @n8wrl XLSX is a macro enabled Excel file. ExcelPackage comes from the EPPlus library, which is tagged in the question.

Comment: Does it still fail if you hardcode the file path?

Comment: @n8wrl Why should it need to be .xlsx? ExcelPackage is from the EPPPlus library

Comment: @drkmtr I just tried putting in one of the paths as static and it still failed

Comment: @mason I have a unedited version of all the files and they are fine. No problem with opening them.

Comment: If the sheet at this position in the index exists I'm out of ideas, I think if it was me I'd look at creating a new file in code, writing to a single cell... then gradually working this code in step-by-step.

Comment: Download the OpenXML Productivity Tool from the Microsoft site.  It has an option to check the validity of a file and point out errors

Comment: `EPPlus` doesn't support `XLSM`. You'll need to go another path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175343/convert-xlsm-to-xlsx

Comment: @Sach I used it to edit xlsm files.

Comment: You can edit but since EPPlus doesn't handle it properly, when saving it corrupts the file. Try doing the same thing but use `.xlsx` extension and it'll work.